# How to build multiple projects in the correct dependency order with Android NDK?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have a series of existing libraries which I need to re-use in an Android application. The layout is similar to:

> \Libraries\libOne
>   \Libraries\libTwo [Static library]
>   \Libraries\libThree
>   \Applications\MyApplication\ [Application]

`libTwo` depends on `libOne`, and `libThree` depends on `libTwo`. How can I get the build system to build all of the libraries in the correct order? I'm trying to use Eclipse, but if necessary I can use the command line.

All of these libraries will eventually be referenced by a Java application (and use JNI to interact with them). Any clues on how I setup the Android.mk / Application.mk files?

I've tried using `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY` for libTwo, but it doesn't actually output any files! I was expecting a `libTwo.a` file, but nothing gets compiled or built.

Do I write one Android.mk in the application? Or an Android.mk for each project?

Comment: Can you share your Android.mk? It's not clear how you set up your projects.

Comment: @AlexCohn I don't have a working Android.mk yet, that's the problem. I'm looking for an answer which describes how to build all three libraries and get them linking together from the main application.

Comment: I understand that you don't have a working Android.mk yet, but you have a not-yet-working one, haven't you?

Answer (score 3):

*OK, now I see your edit, and this makes it possible to answer the specific question.*

You *must* have at least one `Android.mk` file for your application if you want to use Android NDK to build your native library/ies. This is not a requirement, though. It is OK to build it though Cmake, or a "standalone toolchain" with "traditional" makefiles, or with a MS Visual Studio plugin, or any other way. It is the result that matters. The result is a shared object built with a compatible compiler for a bionic runtime.

It makes goode sense to put the library in `${project_root}/libs/armeabi/` directory (for ARM v6 compatible devices, other subdirectories for x86, MIPS, arm v7a) to allow the APK builder pack it correctly, to allow app installer to unpack the correct version (compatible with the device processor) into `/data/data/${package_name}/lib` directory on the device, and finally to be able to use `System.loadLibrary(short_name)` to use it from Java. But it is also quite possible to pack the `so` file differently, unpack it manually, and load it from any place on the device file system (provided your app has permission to write and read this file).

But if we filter out exotic cases, it is much more comfortable to have an Android.mk in the `${project_root}/jni` directory. In terms of `ndk-build` command, each library is a separate MODULE, but all three may be defined in one Android.mk file. On the other hand, if your libraries are isolated (e.g. come from separate 3rd parties), you will probably prefer to create three Android.mk files. Luckily, `ndk-build` is nothing but a wrapper around gnu make, and the simple `include` statement in Android.mk works as in any other makefiles.

In summary, your case is probably covered by a simple `Applications/MyApplication/ [Application]/jni/Android.mk` file:

```
include ../../Libraries/libOne/Android.mk
include ../../Libraries/libTwo/Android.mk
include ../../Libraries/libThree/Android.mk
```

I don't know what dependency you have between libOne and libTwo, but for libOne the file `Libraries/libOne/Android.mk` will look like

```
LOCAL_PATH = $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libOne
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := first.c
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and `Libraries/libThree/Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_PATH = $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libThree
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := third.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libOne $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libTwo
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libOne libTwo
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You should run `ndk-build` from `Applications/MyApplication/ [Application]` directory - either from command prompt, or through Eclipse ADT plugin.

**update** the same may be expressed by one `Android.mk` file in `jni` directory:

```
LOCAL_PATH = ../../Libraries/libOne
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libOne
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := first.c
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH = ../../Libraries/libThree
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libThree
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := third.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libOne $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libTwo
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libOne libTwo
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried using multiple Android.mk files, but it caused problems redefining LOCAL_PATH (`$(call my-dir)` returned the NDK core directory, not the actual directory when not called on the first line!

Comment: Absolutely! `$(call my-dir)` should be one of the very first lines in a file. But this has nothing to do with the question of one or multiple Android.mk files. See **update**

Answer (score 0):

There is an android section in the projects' properties, where you can edit the library dependencies. It can only be used, if     libOne     libTwo and     libThree are marked as libraries, in their properties panel.